# Run a C++ code that was programmed for OpenCV 2.0 with OpenCV 2.4.9

Tags: opencv, compatibility

I have installed OpenCV 2.4.9 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to run a C++ code that was programmed for OpenCV 2.0 with OpenCV 2.4.9. Is that possible? or do I have to install OpenCV 2.0?

I tried but I got the following errors:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include   -Wall -O2 -c common.cpp
g++ -shared -lcv -lcxcore -lhighgui -lm  grid_map.o hough.o io.o  manipulatemap.o common.o -o libmapmerge.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcxcore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui
/usr/bin/ld: grid_map.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTVSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
grid_map.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libmapmerge.so] Error 1
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Those are library names for OpenCV 1.x (cv, cxcore, highgui, ...).
For Opencv 2.x they look like this: opencv_core, opencv_highgui, ...)

I'm not sure if they did include symlinks for older names in 2.0 version,
but you should use the new library names anyway.